# Viewmodel attach to fragment is not working as expected

Tags: android, fragment, viewmodel

I'm kind of new in this Android Architecture, and I'm trying to understand the use of ViewModel.

Currently I have an activity with a fragment embedded in its xml. The fragment just have an edittext whose content I want to persist when the phone rotates. I've implemented the Viewmodel, livedata and observers correctly (I suppose), and attached the ViewModel to the fragment.

The problem comes here, when I rotate the phone the fragment is recreated and the information, gone. But, if I attached the ViewModel to the activity the app works as intended.

So, after some background info, the question is, Why would I want to attach the ViewModel to a fragment if the Viewmodel object is cleared when the fragment is recreated/destroyed?

Thanks

Ps. Here is how I attached the Viewmodel to the activity, this way it works as intended

```
Fragment

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
...
final MuestrasViewModelFactory mvmFactory = new MuestrasViewModelFactory(new String[]{"hello","world","again"});
final MuestrasViewModel mvm = new ViewModelProvider(requireActivity(), mvFactory).get(MuestrasViewModel.class);
... //here comes the observers
```

Comment: Try setting the Fragment as the owner, like this: `final MuestrasViewModel mvm = new ViewModelProvider(this, mvFactory).get(MuestrasViewModel.class);`

Also, you can remove them from the method and declare them directly on the class.

Comment: How are you adding your fragment? Are you sure the fragment is the same restored instance (you can do `toString()` on the fragment and see what the internal ID is)

Comment: The viewModel is attached to the fragment as suggested in the comment (using the keyword this), but on rotation the Fragment is resetted.

Comment: The fragment is declared on the activity layout xml.